# Why if I delete the Packageinstaller apk on Android 6 the whole Android OS crashes?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, root-access

I have a Rooted Moto E 2nd gen(Android 6), and when making experiments on it, I discovered that when I delete Packageinstaller.apk and reboot the device, the whole Android OS crashes. This was not happening on previous versions of Android. Do you know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package installer is also managing permissions (AppOps) since Android 6, removing it means critical package lose permissions you are not supposed to be able to remove, as they are mandatory to proper phone usage.

Comment: Is there a way to disable new apps installation?

Comment: Yes, remove the permission to install package to the target user by making the account a managed account, or hook system to intercept installation window and ask for a password or outright kill it. (What you are looking to intercept is probably com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity). Going to intercept route means you may need to block app stores the same way as they can bypass this if installed on system partition. It will still be possible to install over ADB or recovery if left unprotected.

Comment: "Package Manager" manages permissions including AppOps, not "Package Installer".