# android phone enters bootloop after removing packageinstaller

Tags: 7.0-nougat

I am trying to block my phone from installing packages from unknown sources.

I rooted my device and removed com.android.packageinstaller.
A reboot after this step forces my phone into a bootloop.
There are two questions I have:

1. How is the package com.android.packageinstaller related to the booting process of a phone.
2. Is there any way through which I can block my phone from installing packages from unknown sources. (The switch "Install From Unknown Sources" in the Setting Menu can be toggled easily and does not meet my purpose.)

Model name : Redmi Note 4, 
Android version : 7.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly related and/or duplicate: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/174641/why-if-i-delete-the-packageinstaller-apk-on-android-6-the-whole-android-os-crash, https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186756/how-to-block-from-installing-apk

Comment: Check `logact`. That's an easy way to find root cause of bootloop.